# test significance in difference of proportion in R

Tags: r, comparison, difference, significance

I have a table of the count of individuals for different scenarios. Each row represents a scenario and each column represents a group. I was wondering how i can compare if the differences between the proportions of individuals within each group across scenarios are statistically significant?

for example is the difference of proportion of people withing group ASO different for scenario complete and abandonment?

```
all <- c(207,39,38)
complete <- c(158,32,28)
incomplete <- c(49, 7, 10) 
cse <- c(12,7,4)
abandon <- c(23,2,2)

table <- rbind(all, complete, incomplete, cse, abandon)
table <- as.data.frame(table)
colnames(table) <- c("ASO", "KSO", "TSO")
```

i have found a similiar solution [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/comparison-of-two-proportions-parametric-z-test-and-non-parametric-chi-squared-methods/) where they use the following code to calculate the z-value:

```
z.prop = function(x1,x2,n1,n2){
  numerator = (x1/n1) - (x2/n2)
  p.common = (x1+x2) / (n1+n2)
  denominator = sqrt(p.common * (1-p.common) * (1/n1 + 1/n2))
  z.prop.ris = numerator / denominator
  return(z.prop.ris)
}
```

which i have applied to my example:

```
z.prop (207,23,284,27)
[1] -1.391376
```

Answer (score 0):

A Poisson generalized linear model. First you need to reformat your data

```
table2=data.frame(
  "val"=c(all, complete, incomplete, cse, abandon),
  "grp1"=factor(rep(c("ASO","KSO","TSO"),5)),
  "grp2"=factor(rep(c("all","complete","incomplete","cse","abandon"),each=3))
)

   val grp1       grp2
1  207  ASO        all
2   39  KSO        all
3   38  TSO        all
4  158  ASO   complete
5   32  KSO   complete
6   28  TSO   complete
7   49  ASO incomplete
8    7  KSO incomplete
9   10  TSO incomplete
10  12  ASO        cse
11   7  KSO        cse
12   4  TSO        cse
13  23  ASO    abandon
14   2  KSO    abandon
15   2  TSO    abandon
```

You can build a model on the whole data and then construct appropriate intervals. A quick dirty alternative is to build 3 distinct models for each level of grp1, so for. ex results for "ASO" would be

```
summary(glm(val~grp2,data=subset(table2,grp1=="ASO"),family=poisson))

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)      3.1355     0.2085  15.037  < 2e-16 ***
grp2all          2.1972     0.2198   9.997  < 2e-16 ***
grp2complete     1.9271     0.2232   8.635  < 2e-16 ***
grp2cse         -0.6506     0.3561  -1.827  0.06771 .  
grp2incomplete   0.7563     0.2528   2.992  0.00277 **
```

In this case you are testing whether the first level (the reference - abandon) is different from 0, then each subsequent term tests whether the next level is different from the reference (abandon).

Comment: how would this be interpreted? for example grp1KSO:grp2cse - KSO in cse is significantly different from all the proportion? Does this approach to significance testing do all pairwise comparisons? I am not interested to see if there are differences between ASO, TSO, KSO, only if there are differences in (1) ASO between scenarios, (2) TSO between scenarios and (3) KSO between scenarios

Comment: @Danka Are you only interested in a global test, that is whether there exists a difference between all the values of ASO?

Comment: whether it exists, and if it does, where is it?

Comment: thank you that work. Now i know which proportion differences are significant. But what is the reasoning behíng using a poisson GLM. I am aware that poisson distribution is suitable for count data, but i am not sure how the model works.

Comment: @Danka A linear model is required if you are interested in making arbitrary comparisons between groups, otherwise a Chi-square test can be used for a global test. A Poisson model is just like a regular linear model, except that here we assume the IV is Poisson distributed (and use log link by default), the rest works just like a regular linear model.